# send real time notification to specific user by people id in flutter

Tags: flutter, sockets, notifications, real-time

I am trying to build an app that consist of notification. This notification only notify to some specific user (not broadcast to all user). I have tried to use `firebase_messaging` and it sends notification to specific user by token. But actually I have 10 people with 10 id for each of them, I would like to send notification by id not by token, is there a way to do it or is there any resource that lead me to build notification in an app?

Comment: With FCM there will be a token generated for each user - client (mobile app, web browser...) combination. As far as I know you have to keep track of these tokens and use them to send out notification to one or more users.

Comment: @PeterKoltai because of I can not always track token of user, I would like to send it to specific user by person_id, is it possible to do it with fcm ? or did you know any other package ?

Comment: I'm afraid it is not possible. Check [this out](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/manage-tokens), it explicitly states that you should store tokens in you own backend to be able to find the token of a specific user.

Comment: You can use topic subscription. Each user subscribe to their id as topic, then you can send notification to certain topic and specific user will receive it (subscriber).

Comment: @MiftakhulArzak How to do that, can you share with me about the resource that I can read with detail ?

Comment: Thank you @PeterKoltai but honestly I was worry when token was changing after user doing uinstalll-install app

Comment: @uyhaW There is a listener to get notified when an FCM token changes. Look for `onTokenRefresh` of `FirebaseMessaging.instance`. By listening to this you can update the user's FCM tokens in your database.

Comment: Actually you can update user token value in your database if new token was created as @PeterKoltai suggested. If you want another way, you can see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use topic to send a notification to specific user. Each user subscribe to their id as topic.

```
// use this to subscribe to the topic
// set userId as topic
// you can add this code after user successfully logged in or in home page.
await FirebaseMessaging.instance.subscribeToTopic('userId');

// use this to unsubscribe from the topic
// you can call this code if user logout to avoid receiving a notification.
await FirebaseMessaging.instance.unsubscribeFromTopic('userId');
```

Firebase initialization and notification setting is same as yours before. You can check example documentation [here](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging/example).

Then you can test to send a notification to the topic.
You can use firebase console and set target to topic and fill topic field with user id. Or use postman and send `POST` to url `https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send`, fill raw body

```
{
  "to": "/topics/userId", //change userId with user id value
  "notification" : {
     "body" : "Body of Your Notification",
     "title": "Title of Your Notification"
 },
 "data" : {
     "body" : "Body of Your Notification in Data",
     "title": "Title of Your Notification in Title",
     "key_1" : "Value for key_1",
     "key_2" : "Value for key_2"
 }
}
```

Dont forget to add `Authorization` on the header. See [here](https://medium.com/android-school/test-fcm-notification-with-postman-f91ba08aacc3) for testing firebase notification using postman.